# Readonly folders in Apache installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, apache-2.2

I installed Apache 2.2 on Windows 7 to folder: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2".
Unfortunately, all folders in "Program Files" are for "read only". When I removes this flag from properties of some folder, it come back again.

But my real problem is, that I can not to edit files in folder htdocs. When I editing them in Notepad++, I get following error: "Pleas check whether if this file is oppened in another program". So generaly, I succeed to delete files from htdocs folder, but after that I accept to get administrative control. I think, that if I will succeed to remove the "read only" flag complitely, the problem will solve.

Normally I'm loggin in with non Administrator user (but in Administrators group).
With Administrator I succeed to edit the files, but also failed to remove "read only" flag.

I hope, that you will give me solution other that to work always with Administrator.

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I founded, was to install the server to "C:\Apache2.2\" instead of "Program Files" folder.
Despite that, that attribute "read only" still exists, I do succeed to change the files with non Administrator user.